# header overlapping with div content when saving the file as pdf

Tags: javascript

In my code I have a function called `handleprint()` which gets called on image click. This function is basically for printing and saving the file as pdf.

```
<img src ='pix/pdf.png' id="print" onclick="handleprint();"></img>  
<script>
function handleprint() {
     var printContents = document.getElementById('total').innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}  //total is the div that get print

</script>
```

Problem here is that the generated pdf header(window header) is sometimes [overlapping with the div content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/807Ni.png). How can I resolve this issue ?
[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/807Ni.png)

Comment: Where is there any pdf getting generated

Comment: window.print() method is invoked when i click on image and then the print window gives the option "save file as pdf"

Comment: i have wasted hack of time in this. Can any one resolve this ?

Comment: Problem will most likely be sloppy HTML and CSS

Comment: Yes it is sloppy and Thanks.